# validating a model when using a custom model binder in webapi2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am executing a custom `WebApi2` model binder as follows:
This is creating the model successfully. I am suppressing the JSON serializer errors as they don't correspond to the same errors that are normally provided by the default model binder.

Regardless or 'required' and other attributes on the model, the ModelState is empty.

*How do I either*

- Invoke the **default model binder** to obtain the PartyModel with all the relevant model state errors?
- Execute the default model validator to fill the Model State with the relevant errors after serializing what properties I can?

.

```
    public bool BindModel(
       HttpActionContext actionContext, 
       System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(PartyModel))
            return false;

        var json = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
                // ignore json serializer errors, as they don't
                // seem to mimic the webapi2 default validator names/descriptions.
                Error = (s, e) => e.ErrorContext.Handled = true
            };
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PartyModel>(json, settings);  

        // at this point the model needs to be validated.

        bindingContext.Model = model;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public bool BindModel(
         HttpActionContext actionContext,  
         System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(PartyModel))
            return false;
        ...

        // following lines invoke default validation on model
        bindingContext.ValidationNode.ValidateAllProperties = true;
        bindingContext.ValidationNode.Validate(actionContext);
        return true;
    }
```